# Visual Studio - Comments add an extra indent

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2015, comments, indentation

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Whenever I add any kind of comment, any new line after the comment has an extra indent. I have noticed this behavior in both C++ and C#.

This is what I get so far:

```
// Comment with correct indenting
     public void TestMethod() { }
```

It should be:

```
//Comment with corrent indenting
public void TestMethod() { }
```

How do I stop the former from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try indenting the whole file using Ctrl + K + D .... I think that should solve the issue.

Comment: Nope, no visible changes to my code and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the indentation automatically made by visual studio, select all code by pressing `Ctrl+a` , then Press `Shift+Tab`twice to remove the indentation that was automatically made by Visual Studio.

And if you want to disable that auto-formatting feature permanently: Goto **Tool>Options>Text Editor>C#>Advanced**  (and then uncheck the options that are not required).